# Orion notification complex payload

Tags: fiware-orion, plivo

I'm trying to use Orion notification to send SMS with Plivo.
This is how I send an SMS directly with Plivo:

```
curl -X POST https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/MAMDA5ZDJIMDM1/Message/ -L -u MAMDA5ZDJIM:YzhiNDJjODNhNDkxMjhiYTgxZD -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- <<EOF
{
   "src": "0039414141414",
   "dst": "0039414747111",
   "text": "test SMS"
}
EOF
```

How should I encode it in Orion? I tried:

```
curl localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json'  -d @- <<EOF
{
  "description": "A subscription to get info about WS_UPPA_Sensor2",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "id": "Sensor1",
        "type": "SensingDevice"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "temperature"
      ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "httpCustom": {
      "url": "https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/MAMDA5ZDJIMDM1NZVMZD/Message/",
      "headers": {
         "Authorization": "Basic TUFNREE1WkRKSU1ETTFOWlZNWkQ6WXpoaU5ESmpPRE5oTkRreE1qaGlZVGd4WkRkaE5qYzNPV1ZsTnpZMA=="
      },
      "payload": "{%22src%22%3A%2200393806412092%22%2C%22dst%22%3A%2200393806412093%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22test%20SMS%20from%20Waziup%22}"

    },
    "attrs": [
      "temperature"
    ]
  },
  "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
  "throttling": 5
}
EOF
```

Is there another way than percent encoding?

Answer (score 0):

[URL encoding](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php) (I understand is the one you refer by "percent encoding") is the only one which have an special treatment in custom notifications (details described as [part of the Orion documentation](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/forbidden_characters/#custom-payload-special-treatment)).

In fact, taking into account the existing one is complete (I mean, any text can be expressed in the terms of URL encoding) there is no need of adding any other.

Comment: As seen in http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/forbidden_characters/#specific-restrictions-for-id-fields
I encoded my payload like that:

    "payload": "{ %22src%22: %2200393806412092%22, %22dst%22: %2200393806412093%22, %22text%22: %22test%22}"

Is it correct? Only the quotes need to be escaped (not "}" or ":" or ",") ?

Comment: That's correct. "}", ":" and "," are not forbiden chars so they can be use directly. I'd suggest to check what is Orion actually sending, e.g. using the http://requestb.in tool (adjusting subscription `"url"` accordingly, of course).